# Arc parameter equation

Tags: parametric

So, I have the function $y=-x^2+3$, and I'm to generate the parametric equation for the arc that is above $y=x$. I got from $-x^2+3>x$ to  $\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{-2}<x<\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{-2}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now use the parametrization $(x, -x^2+3)$, and you are done.